# How to test a model instance method which makes a call to an external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I am having trouble understanding what to test in the case below and how to do it.

I have the following instance method on Address model

```
validate :address, on: [:create, :update]

def address
    check = CalendarEventLocationParsingWorker.new.perform("", self.structured, true )
    if check[:code] != 0
      errors.add(:base,"#{self.kind.capitalize} Address couldn't be analysed, please fill up as much fields as possible.")
    else
      self.lat = check[:coords]["lat"]
      self.lon = check[:coords]["lng"]
    end
  end
```

Basically its a method called on create and update hooks and checks with a third party API if the address is valid. How can i test this in isolation without making an actual call to the 3rd party api but rather simulate the response?

I read about mocks and stubs but i do not quite get them yet. Any insight is welcome. Using Rspec, shoulda matchers and factory girl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) or [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gems to stub external api responses

An example with webmock:

```
stub_request(:get, "your external api url")
  .to_return(code: 0, coords: { lat: 1, lng: 2 })

# test your address method here
```

With [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) you can run your test once and it will make an actual call to external api, record its resonse to `.yml` file and then reuse it in all later tests. If external api response changes you can just delete `.yml` file and record a new sample response.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, can i do without making the actual request though not even once?

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou  Yes, use webmock for this

Answer (score 0):

You can stub `perform` method on any instance of `CalendarEventLocationParsingWorker` to return desired value

Syntax:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Class).to receive(:method).and_return(:return_value)
```

Ex:

```
allow_any_instance_of(CalendarEventLocationParsingWorker).to receive(:perform).and_return({code: 0})
```

Refer: [Allow a message on any instance of a class](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/allow-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class)